# How do I rotate captureManager saved photo in WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I wrote a simple code in C# and VS2013 for Lumia 640 XL WP 8.1, like an example photo app. Not too bad, but it's have an little problem: when the picture saved to the media, then this picture is rotated 90 degrees to left.

Here is my code for setting preview area:

```
captureManager = new MediaCapture();
await captureManager.InitializeAsync();
captureManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
captureManager.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
cptElement.Source = captureManager;
await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
```

And here is the code for capture:

```
ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);
```

So, you may see, i tried to rotate a finally picture in this commandline:

```
captureManager.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
```

but it was not worked.

What do I do in this case?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my pure english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at the [CameraStarterKit SDK sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit). It will show you how to do rotation of:

Preview:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current orientation of the UI in relation to the device (when AutoRotationPreferences cannot be honored) and applies a corrective rotation to the preview
/// </summary>
private async Task SetPreviewRotationAsync()
{
    // Only need to update the orientation if the camera is mounted on the device
    if (_externalCamera) return;

    // Calculate which way and how far to rotate the preview
    int rotationDegrees = ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(_displayOrientation);

    // The rotation direction needs to be inverted if the preview is being mirrored
    if (_mirroringPreview)
    {
        rotationDegrees = (360 - rotationDegrees) % 360;
    }

    // Add rotation metadata to the preview stream to make sure the aspect ratio / dimensions match when rendering and getting preview frames
    var props = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
    props.Properties.Add(RotationKey, rotationDegrees);
    await _mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, props, null);
}
```

Photos:

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a photo to a StorageFile and adds rotation metadata to it
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task TakePhotoAsync()
{
    // While taking a photo, keep the video button enabled only if the camera supports simultaneously taking pictures and recording video
    VideoButton.IsEnabled = _mediaCapture.MediaCaptureSettings.ConcurrentRecordAndPhotoSupported;

    // Make the button invisible if it's disabled, so it's obvious it cannot be interacted with
    VideoButton.Opacity = VideoButton.IsEnabled ? 1 : 0;

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Taking photo...");
        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
        Debug.WriteLine("Photo taken!");

        var photoOrientation = ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(GetCameraOrientation());

        await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, photoOrientation);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking a photo: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

And videos:

```
/// <summary>
/// Records an MP4 video to a StorageFile and adds rotation metadata to it
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task StartRecordingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Create storage file in Pictures Library
        var videoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("SimpleVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        var encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

        // Calculate rotation angle, taking mirroring into account if necessary
        var rotationAngle = 360 - ConvertDeviceOrientationToDegrees(GetCameraOrientation());
        encodingProfile.Video.Properties.Add(RotationKey, PropertyValue.CreateInt32(rotationAngle));

        Debug.WriteLine("Starting recording...");

        await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, videoFile);
        _isRecording = true;

        Debug.WriteLine("Started recording!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception when starting video recording: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

But you should look at the full sample to see where the orientation/rotation information is coming from, and to get the helper functions as well.